# Access a variable of a content script from another one in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I maintain a Firefox add-on developed with the add-on SDK (based on `jpm` tool). It uses two content scripts: one to inject an external library (highlight.js) into the page, and the other one to call a function from the first script.

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|                Add-on script               |
+--------------------------------------------+
            |                    |
+-----------|--------------------|-----------+
| +---------V--------+  +--------V---------+ |
| | highlight.min.js |  | enlightscript.js | |
| |                  |  |                  | |
| |      hljs.func() <--- calling          | |
| +------------------+  +------------------+ |
|                                   web page |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Until recently, I had no problem to do so: I could inject the two content scripts from the add-on script (complete code [here](https://github.com/Qeole/Enlight/blob/master/index.js#L178)):

```js
...
contentScriptFile: [
  self.data.url(script_dir + "/highlight.min.js"),
  self.data.url("enlightscript.js")
]
...
```

And call a function attached to an object defined in the first script inside the second one (code [here](https://github.com/Qeole/Enlight/blob/master/data/enlightscript.js#L90)):

```js
// defined in highlight.min.js, called from enlightscript.js
hljs.initHighlighting();
```

This was possible because the `window.hljs` object was defined in the first script as follows:

```js
// definition in highlight.min.js
window.hljs = some_function_definition();
```

But this library is evolving, and in a recent [commit](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/commit/d6207b0720e457bdf4646202336c3d2bef6ce642) this definition has turned into:

```js
// new definition in highlight.min.js
// (it is supposed to be called either in the global namespace,
// in which case self is equivalent to window, or from within a
// worker)
self.hljs = some_function_definition();
```

In my case the `self` object does not refer to the `window`, and I can no more call the function directly. So far I have not found any working solution.

Note that I can absolutely not edit the `highlight.min.js` script (so I cannot revert the modification or change the way it is called).

Would someone know whether it is possible to reach and call that `hljs.initHighlighting();` function from the second script (`enlightscript.js`)?

#### Edit:

I have contacted the developers of the library and they kindly modified their code, so I have no more issue to call my object. I would still be interested in answers − for the record.